# Passing an array from a VBScript to another VBScript

Tags: arrays, vbscript, parameter-passing

I want to know if it is possible to pass an array from a VBScript to another.

Actually what I'm trying to achieve is passing a 2D array to the other VBScript.

What I intended to do is, I run a script to copy files to specific folders in the Local Computer, part of a software deployment (That doesn't need installation).

But because I'm doing this to multiple software, I'm creating a general template with my functions.

What I'm stuck in now is creating shortcuts. (A Template to create multiple shortcuts).

So I'm intending to send a 2D array.

Here is an example:

```
Application Group 1
Installation Scripts Starts
'
'
Some Code
'
'
After files of Applications are copied
'
'
Run Shortcut Deployment(send a 2D of array with it)
'
'
Shortcuts Deployed
'
'
Installation Scripts Ends
```

Then

```
Application Group 2
Installation Scripts Starts
'
'
Different code
'
'
Run Same Shortcut Deployment(but a different 2D of array with it)
'
'
Shortcuts Deployed
'
'
Installation Scripts Ends
```

For instance (0,0) will contain Shortcut Name & (0,1) will contain Application Path.
(1,0) will contain another Application's shortcut name & (1,1) will contain another Application Path.

And so on....

Is there anyway to do such a thing?

Comment: There is no elegant way of doing this. Why don't you send all this information as [command line arguments](http://ss64.com/vb/arguments.html)?

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this by command line arguments?

Comment: Generally that can be realized in many ways. If the script processes will be running simultaneously (first one runs second and waits untill it ends), then the array in the first script (or any other variable) can be accessed directly from the second via mutiprocess environment. If they launched one after another, then the array should be serialized first to be passed as string. Another method is to implement Include function, thus the Shortcut Deployment script file can be run within another scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A simple demo

**script1.vbs**

```
Dim objShell

varShort1 = "Shortcut1"
varShort2 = "Shortcut2"
varApp1 = "C:\path1"
varApp2 = "C:\path2"

Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "script2.vbs " & varShort1 & " " & varApp1 & " " & varShort2 & " " & varApp2, True
Set objShell = Nothing

wscript.quit
```

**script2.vbs**

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

For Each arg In args
  Wscript.Echo arg
Next

wscript.quit
```